# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis and ORA-06512: at line 16

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

For the below procedure I am getting the ora error as mentioned in the title while running in Oracle SQL developer

```
DECLARE

sqlstr VARCHAR2(1000);

CURSOR TabSubPartitions IS
SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PART_TABLE'
ORDER BY PARTITION_NAME;

BEGIN

    FOR aSubPart IN TabSubPartitions LOOP
       IF TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) = '31-07-2020' THEN
          sqlstr := 'ALTER TABLE '||aSubPart.TABLE_NAME||' MODIFY PARTITION '||aSubPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' ADD SUBPARTITION ' ||aSubPart.PARTITION_NAME||'_'||TO_CHAR(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))+1, 'MON_YYYY')||' VALUES LESS THAN ( '||TO_DATE(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))+2, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' , 'NLS_CALENDER=GREGORIAN')||')' ; 
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
  END;
```

Could anyone please help me. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have several pieces of advice.

First, modify your code to output the value of `sqlstr`, so you can see exactly what the SQL statement is that you are trying to execute.  This should make it easier to understand where the syntax error is.

Second, change `TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) = '31-07-2020'` to use an explicit date format when converting from date to string. Something like `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)), 'DD-MM-YYYY') ...`.  I don't think this is related to your error, but it is better practice than relying on the implicit conversion format.

Third, look carefully at the `TO_DATE` call. As it is you appear to be calling TO_DATE with date parameter, then implicitly converting that back to a string. At best that's not necessary, and at worst it will cause unexpected behavior.  I suspect you may simply mean to use TO_CHAR where you currently have TO_DATE.

Comment: Hello Dave, many thanks writing to me. I am new to PL/SQL. Could you please guide me on your 1st point: how to get the output of sqlstr so that I can analyse the syntax error.

Comment: @Sneha: That would be `dbms_output.put_line(sqlstr);`

Answer (score 3):

The main issue in the block itself is is here:

```
'NLS_CALENDER=GREGORIAN'
```

where it must be

```
'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'
```

Moreover, you should not rely on implicite date conversions.

But there is also an issue with your resulting `ALTER TABLE` statement, which looks something like

```
ALTER TABLE MODIFY PARTITION ... VALUES LESS THAN ( 02.08.2020 00:00:00)
```

depending on session date settings (again because of implict date conversion). I doubt that Oracle accepts a timestamp like this. Make sure you produce a proper date literal (like `DATE '2020-08-02'`) instead.

The whole corrected code:

```
DECLARE
  sqlstr VARCHAR2(1000);

  CURSOR TabSubPartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PART_TABLE'
    ORDER BY PARTITION_NAME;
BEGIN
  FOR aSubPart IN TabSubPartitions LOOP
    IF TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) = DATE '2020-07-31' THEN
      sqlstr := 
        'ALTER TABLE ' || aSubPart.TABLE_NAME || ' MODIFY PARTITION ' || aSubPart.PARTITION_NAME ||
        ' ADD SUBPARTITION '  || aSubPart.PARTITION_NAME || '_' || TO_CHAR(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))+1, 'MON_YYYY') ||
        ' VALUES LESS THAN (DATE ''' || TRIM(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))+2, 'SYYYY-MM-DD', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) || ''')' ; 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I can now understand where all I have got errors. Many many thanks.